# Should Qt builds run on other computers?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I made a desktop application based on Qt 5.12 on Debian 10 32 bits. Because Qt 5.12 isn’t available via apt-get (I need 2D chart features introduced on 5.12) I compiled Qt from source.

That application is supposed to run on another computer, also Debian 10 32 bits. So I copied the required Qt dependencies from the development machine. It’s working fine.

Is this approach fine or Qt should be compiled on each computer, since hardware specs aren’t identical?

Comment: That wouldn't work once you want to deploy the software to end users etc. Usually one would provide self-contained installers/.dmgs for Windows/macOS, and distro-specific packages for the various distributions (see e.g. OpenSUSE build service), or go for self-contained packages (see https://appimage.org).

Comment: I copied Qt dependencies to another computer and application seems to be running fine there. What should not work? Is it mandatory to compile Qt on each machine? I would believe on that, although so far I don’t have arguments to justify it.

Comment: One possible problem is incompatibilities with other libraries, such as libstdc++ and libc. When creating distribution packages, one would usually use the Qt provided by the distribution. I guess AppImage causes the least headache here. But it always depends on what kind of Software you want to distribute to whom. Is it open source or proprietary software? How many target platforms do you actually need to support? Do you control the target computers? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt, like other shared libraries, need not be compiled on each computer.  It is fine to compile on one machine and then deploy to other machines; this is what distributions such as Debian do.

However, having said that, if you're going to deploy the application to multiple machines, you'll want to do more packaging than just copying the libraries.  Usually users build software into an OS package (so a `.deb` file for Debian) and distribute it that way.  You also need to verify that the libraries are built in a generic way (e.g., without `-march=native`) or your program will crash or perform poorly on systems which have different hardware from the machine on which you compiled it.

Unless you absolutely require Qt 5.12 and can't live without the features in this new version, you may find your life is greatly simplified by using the Qt 5.11 package in Debian 10 already.  You will generally find that your users will also appreciate not having to install a whole different version of Qt, and you will appreciate not having to handle security updates for a library you don't normally maintain.  If you don't intend to actively monitor Qt for security updates and apply them to the version you're shipping, then it would be a disservice to your users to ship your own version, and you should rely on the distro version instead.

Comment: I put everything on a zip, application + Qt dependencies, and an `install.sh`. So I hope not to have much complains about deployment. This is much easier than making a `.deb`, right? And if user decides to run this on non Debian Linux it might still work, right?

Comment: In general, trying to do a single build across distros is going to be a problem.  Qt usually links against OpenSSL, and that differs greatly across distros.  Also, most people won't install your app if you don't package it; it shows that you don't care enough about integrating properly with the rest of the system, and it prevents the package manager from making sure your code continues to work.